# NSUserDefaults for saving info

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want my app to save data like id,name and other stuff,and i want to do it with NSUserDefaults, the problem is that i want to determine some data to be default until the user decide to change them, for example, i want the id number will be 1000 and when the user change the value it will be always the new value.

Comment: So...what have you tried so far? We're not going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the settings bundle to the app, you may specify a default value for each option that you put within the .plist file.  Therefore, there will always be a default value until the user changes it.

Here is a snippet from a .plist file within my settings bundle:
[image]

within the application, I just pull the setting like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *dataMode  = [defaults objectForKey: @"data"];
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`registerDefaults:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults%3a) like this:

```
NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000], @"MyKey",
                                      nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];

NSInteger value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"MyKey"]; // will be 1000 until changed by saving to NSUserDefaults
```

edit: Keep in mind that you have to run this piece of code each time you start your app. Those defaults are not saved to disk.

Comment: [Here's the description in Apple's developer documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html)